# How to test main function in gin application?

Tags: go, testing, program-entry-point, go-gin

How can I test `func main`? Like this:

```
func main(){
     Engine := GetEngine() // returns gin router with handlers atttached 
     Engine.Run(":8080")
}
```

It has only 2 lines but I'd like to have them covered. 
`TestMain'` is reserved for test preparation, does that mean testing `main` was not planned by language creators?
I can move the contents to another function `mainReal` but it seems to be some over engineering?

How to test gin has started well? Can I launch `main` in separate goroutine, check reply and stop it?

Thanks.

P.S. Possible duplicate is not precise duplicate because it is dedicated not to testing of func `main()` itself, but rather ideas to move in outside and so contains different issue and approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test the main package functions in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352239/how-to-test-the-main-package-functions-in-golang)

Comment: I've seen that post but it's not the same, there're some different aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution.

You may test function `main()` from package `main` the same way, just do not name it `TestMain`. I launch it as a separate goroutine, than try to connect to it and perform any request.

I decided to connect to auxilary handler which should respond with a simple json `{"status": "ok"}`.
In my case:

```
func TestMainExecution(t *testing.T) {
    go main()
    resp, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/checkHealth") 
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Cannot make get: %v\n", err)
    }
    bodySb, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Error reading body: %v\n", err)
    }
    body := string(bodySb)
    fmt.Printf("Body: %v\n", body)
    var decodedResponse interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(bodySb, &decodedResponse)
    if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Cannot decode response <%p> from server. Err: %v", bodySb, err)
    }
    assert.Equal(t, map[string]interface{}{"status": "ok"}, decodedResponse,
            "Should return status:ok")
}
```