# How to test the main package in Golang from a "test" package?

Tags: api, unit-testing, go

I have a simple program written in Golang. It's an API. So inside the project folder, there's a folder named `cmd` containing my `main` package (used to initialise the app and defines the endpoints for the API). There's also a folder named after my program, containing multiple files from a package also named after my program. This package serves as the model to do all the necessary queries and contains all the types I have defined.

I also created a folder called `test`. It contains all my test files under the package named `test`. The problem is that to run the tests, I have to access my main package ! Is there a way to do that in Golang ? I tried simply using `import "cmd/main"` but of course it doesn't work.

I also had an idea. Perhaps I could move all my initialising functions (in the `cmd` folder) to the package named after my program. This way I could do a regular `import` in `test`. And I create, inside of `cmd`, a `main.go` in the `main` package that serves as the entry point for the compiler.

I'm new to Go so I'm not really confident. Do you think it's the right way ?

Thanks.

EDIT : Apparently some people think this question is a duplicate, but it's not. Here's the explanation I gave in on of the comments :

> I read this post before posting, but it didn't answer my question
>   because in that post the person has his tests in the main package. The
>   reason why I asked my question is because I don't want to have my
>   tests in the main package. I'd rather have them all in a test folder
>   inside the same package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test the main package functions in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352239/how-to-test-the-main-package-functions-in-golang)

Comment: I read this post before posting, but it didn't answer my question because in that post the person has his tests in the main package. The reason why I asked my question is because I don't want to have my tests in the main package. I'd rather have them all in a `test` folder inside the same package.

Comment: @Flimzy I edited my post, if you're a moderator could you remove the "duplicate" header please ?

Comment: "in a test folder inside the same package" isn't possible in Go. Packages are folder-scoped.

Comment: You can’t import “main”, so you test it from within the “main” package. There l’s not point in fighting the go tools, just do it the same way as every other project.

Comment: It may help if you can show your directory structure as a figure or simple text with appropriate indentations or use output of `tree` command (in Linux) to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not not possible in GO (assuming you want to test private functions).

> because I don't want to have my tests in the main package. I'd rather
>   have them all in a test folder inside the same package.

Your code belongs to different package if you move it into different folder.

This is how GO defines packages https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization:

> Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a **single**
>   directory.

This is how your code structured:

```
main
| -- main.go (package main)
+ -- test
     | -- main_test.go (package test)
```

It is idiomatic to keep tests in the same folder with code. It is normal if language or framework set some rules that developer has to follow. GO is pretty strict about that.

This is how you can organize your code:

```
main
| -- main.go (package main)
| -- main_test.go (package main_test)
| -- main_private_test.go (package main)
```

Often it makes sense to test code against its pubic interfaces. The best way to do that that, is to put tests into different package. GO convention is to keep tests in the same folder what leads to using the same package name. There is a workaround for that issue. You can add `_test` (package main_test) prefix to package name for your tests.

If, that is not possible to test your code using public interfaces, you can add another file with tests and use `package main` in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if all my tests need to have access to the same function(s) ? For example, in my tests I often need to empty some tables so I have a function called "clearTable(tableName)". Is there a proper way of sharing all those functions or should I just copy - paste the functions I want to share for each file ?

Comment: @tomfl Functions have package scope.  Put the functions in any package file.  If the functions are only used in tests, out the functions in a _test.go file.

Comment: @tomfl I typically move all shared testing routines into dedicated package called `mock`. In my case it is mocks for repositories and external services that reused in tests against different packages. You need is slightly different, but solution is the same. So, tests are still stored close to code in the same package as code, but utilities are stored in dedicated package.