# Test main package using "package main_test"

Tags: go

I have a `main.go` and `main_test.go`, and `go test` works fine:

```
$ cat main.go
package main

func main() {}

func F() int { return 1 }

$ cat main_test.go
package main

import "testing"

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    if F() != 1 {
        t.Fatalf("error")
    }
}
```

From [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997114/how-to-test-the-main-package-in-golang-from-a-test-package) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998250/proper-packageT-naming-for-testing-with-the-go-language), I could use `package main_test` in `main_test.go`. But `go test` shows `./main_test.go:6:5: undefined: F`. How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the main package. Use the following code assuming that the package path is "example.com/example".

```
$ cat main_test.go
package main

import (
     "testing"
     "example.com/example"   // import main
)

func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    if main.F() != 1 {      // use package selector when referring to F
        t.Fatalf("error")
    }
}
```

Replace `example.com/example` with the actual path of your package.